# how to select clicked button to change it classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide two button and show another buttons when edit button clicked but the problem is when I click on edit button all of the buttons on table react to this event .

I used $(this) to select the clicked button but it works just for edit button and other button doesn't follow this rule.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".cat-edit-btn", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("d-inline d-none");
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("tr").find(".cat-delete-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none");
  $(this).parent().find($(".cat-sub-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none"));
  $(this).parent().find($(".cat-cancell-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered bg-info table-striped text-center" style="direction:rtl; text-align:right !important;">
  <thead style="font-size: 16px">
    <tr style="color: white; background-color: darkcyan">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>پیش نمایش</th>
      <th>نام کاتالوگ</th>
      <th>دسته بندی</th>
      <th>زبان</th>
      <th>تاریخ انتشار</th>
      <th>توضیحات</th>
      <th colspan="3">مدیریت</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="font-size: 15px">

    <tr>
      <td>پیش نمایش</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_TITLE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>
        <span>انگلیسی</span>
      </td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DATE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DESC</td>
      <td>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-1 cat-edit-btn d-inline">ویرایش</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-success ml-1 cat-sub-btn ">ثبت</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-info ml-1 cat-cancell-btn">انصراف</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cat-delete-btn d-inline">حذف</button>
        <input class="d-none" id="category_id" value="@item.CATALOG_ID" />

      </td>



    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>پیش نمایش</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_TITLE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>

        <span>فارسی</span>
      </td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DATE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DESC</td>
      <td>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-1 cat-edit-btn d-inline">ویرایش</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-success ml-1 cat-sub-btn ">ثبت</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-info ml-1 cat-cancell-btn">انصراف</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cat-delete-btn d-inline">حذف</button>
        <input class="d-none" id="category_id" value="@item.CATALOG_ID" />

      </td>



    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace the template stuff with actual HTML since it is not a template question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are having wrong selectors to target relative elements. You need to traverse to closest row element and then find target elements in it:

```
 var $closestRow = $(this).closest('tr')
 $closestRow.find(".cat-delete-btn,.cat-sub-btn,.cat-cancell-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and short down your code:

```
$(this).closest("td").find(".cat-delete-btn,.cat-sub-btn,.cat-cancell-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none");
```

Please note that in some of your `.find` method you had `$(` as in `.find($(".cat-sub-btn")`. There is no need to use `$()` inside a `.find()`

Also the logic in your `.parent().parent().parent().find("tr")` would mean that you go to the `tbody` and then search for all `tr`, aka why it affects all of your buttons.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', ".cat-edit-btn", function() {

  //$(this).toggleClass("d-inline d-none");

  $(this).closest("td").find(".cat-delete-btn,.cat-sub-btn,.cat-cancell-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none");

});
```

```css
.d-none{
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered bg-info table-striped text-center" style="direction:rtl; text-align:right !important;">
  <thead style="font-size: 16px">
    <tr style="color: white; background-color: darkcyan">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>پیش نمایش</th>
      <th>نام کاتالوگ</th>
      <th>دسته بندی</th>
      <th>زبان</th>
      <th>تاریخ انتشار</th>
      <th>توضیحات</th>
      <th colspan="3">مدیریت</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="font-size: 15px">

    
    <tr>
      <td>پیش نمایش</td>
      <td>TITLE</td>
      <td>CATEGORY</td>
      <td>_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>

        <span>فارسی</span> 

      </td>
      <td>CATALOG_DATE</td>
      <td>CATALOG_DESC</td>
      <td>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-1 cat-edit-btn d-inline">ویرایش</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-success ml-1 cat-sub-btn ">ثبت</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-info ml-1 cat-cancell-btn">انصراف</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cat-delete-btn d-inline">حذف</button>
        <input class="d-none" id="category_id" value="@item.CATALOG_ID" />

      </td>



    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>پیش نمایش</td>
      <td>TITLE</td>
      <td>CATEGORY</td>
      <td>_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>

        <span>فارسی</span> 

      </td>
      <td>CATALOG_DATE</td>
      <td>CATALOG_DESC</td>
      <td>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-1 cat-edit-btn d-inline">ویرایش</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-success ml-1 cat-sub-btn ">ثبت</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-info ml-1 cat-cancell-btn">انصراف</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cat-delete-btn d-inline">حذف</button>
        <input class="d-none" id="category_id" value="@item.CATALOG_ID" />

      </td>



    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is using jquery selectors `$` within your `.find` command, you don't need to do this - i.e.

```
$(this).parent().find($(".cat-sub-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none"));
```

Should be:

```
$(this).parent().find(".cat-sub-btn").toggleClass("d-inline d-none");
```

You can dramatically simplify your jquery code. I've changed the class for your cancel button because it looked like there was a typo `.cat-cancell-btn` -> `.cat-cancel-btn`.

---

### Recommended solution

The code below is a little different, as it assumes that the buttons should all be switched (as your current code is attempting). You can use `.closest("td")` to find the nearest cell (i.e. the one containing all buttons) and then find all buttons with `.find("btn")` before toggling the class for each of them using `.toggleClass("d-none")`

---

## Demo

```js
$(document).on('click', ".cat-edit-btn, .cat-cancel-btn", function() {

  $(this).closest("td").find(".btn").toggleClass("d-none");

});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered bg-info table-striped text-center" style="direction:rtl; text-align:right !important;">
  <thead style="font-size: 16px">
    <tr style="color: white; background-color: darkcyan">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>پیش نمایش</th>
      <th>نام کاتالوگ</th>
      <th>دسته بندی</th>
      <th>زبان</th>
      <th>تاریخ انتشار</th>
      <th>توضیحات</th>
      <th colspan="3">مدیریت</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="font-size: 15px">


    <tr>
      <td>پیش نمایش</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_TITLE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>

        <span>فارسی</span>

        <span>انگلیسی</span>

      </td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DATE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DESC</td>
      <td>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-1 cat-edit-btn d-inline">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-success ml-1 cat-sub-btn ">Sub</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-info ml-1 cat-cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cat-delete-btn d-inline">Delete</button>
        <input class="d-none" id="category_id" value="@item.CATALOG_ID" />

      </td>



    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>پیش نمایش</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_TITLE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_CATEGORY</td>
      <td>

        <span>فارسی</span>

        <span>انگلیسی</span>

      </td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DATE</td>
      <td>@item.CATALOG_DESC</td>
      <td>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-1 cat-edit-btn d-inline">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-success ml-1 cat-sub-btn ">Sub</button>
        <button type="button" class="d-none btn btn-info ml-1 cat-cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cat-delete-btn d-inline">Delete</button>
        <input class="d-none" id="category_id" value="@item.CATALOG_ID" />

      </td>



    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```